# Facebook FQL properly sorting stream table using ORDER BY created_time

Tags: facebook, sorting, stream, facebook-fql, posts

I'm having some trouble to retrieve a sequence of posts using FQL when sorting by *created_time*. It seems that when I try to retrieve posts ordering by *created_time*, FQL first retrieves the first 50 posts (LIMIT 50) ordered by *updated_time* and then apply *ORDER BY* on these first 50 posts.

The *updated_time* datetime gets updated whenever someone comments on that post, so if someone comments on a post that's 1 year old, the last post from my first query will be that post and my next sequence will start from that point in time (older than 1 year).

This causes me a problem because to get the next 50 posts in the sequence, I have to use the *created_time* datetime from the last post from the first query.

Any ideas on how to this the correct way?

`SELECT post_id,actor_id,message,created_time,updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=xxx AND created_time < xxxxxxxx ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 50`

---

Example:

There is a post with timestamps: 'updated_time': 1372837741 and 'created_time': 1372081023

With the following query, there are no results although the post's created_time is inside the specified created_time range.

`SELECT post_id,actor_id,message,permalink,created_time,updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=xxxxxxxxx
AND created_time < 1372081033
AND created_time > 1372081013`

But if I change the query's range to include the post's updated_time, the post above is returned.

`SELECT post_id,actor_id,message,permalink,created_time,updated_time FROM stream WHERE source_id=xxxxxxxxxxx
AND created_time < 1372837742 AND created_time > 1372081013`

This is probably a bug.

---

Thanks in advance!